# set css styles with variables in ruby on rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4

I try to do this : [final result](http://postimg.org/image/8tcdpnf9r/). For this I have put a other image (this one : [cover](http://postimg.org/image/57aszzear/)) on the first. And for the border color, I have created a class "[parallelogram](http://jsfiddle.net/9DN5q/96/)".

HTML File :

```
<%= image_tag(project.projectpicture.url(:slider), :class => "image") %>
<%= image_tag(("/assets/coverslider.png"), :class => "cover") %>
<div class="parallelogram" style="background: red;"></div>
```

CSS File :

```
.image
 {
    position: relative;
 }

 .cover
 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
 }

 .parallelogram
 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left:227px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    width:10px; 
    height:200px; 
    transform: skew(20deg); 
    -webkit-transform: skew(20deg);
  }
```

All of this works. I dont know if it the best solution and I am open at every better solution.

Now I want to have the possibility to change the parallelogram color. For that I tried :

```
<div class="parallelogram" style="background: #{project.color};"></div>
```

Where project.color is the project color. This doesn't work. Rails generates this html code :

```
<img class="image" src="/system/projects/projectpictures/0..." alt="15"></img>
<img class="cover" src="/assets/coverslider.png" alt="Coverslider"></img>
<div class="parallelogram" style="background: #{project.color};"></div>
```

I don't know why the #{project.color} doesn't set the color and stays like this.

Thank you for your help. I begin so if you have a better solution, I will be happy to learn it.

Comment: Do you have `color` attribute in your `projects` table?

Comment: Yes. When I do a : `<%= link_to project.name, project_path(project), style: "background: #{project.color};" %>` Rails generates the good code : `<a style="background: #FF004F" href="http://localhost:3000/projects/21"></a>` and turns `#{project.color}` into `#FF004F`. I don't know why Rails doesn't do the same with `<div>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know why Rails doesn't do the same with `<div>`

Because `div` tag belongs to `HTML` not `Rails`.You can't just give `#{project.color}` in the `HTML div`.

**Solution**

There is a `div_for` tag for `Rails`,try with it.

For more info,see this **[API](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/RecordTagHelper/div_for)**

**OR**

Try using with **[content_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag)**

Comment: This is a good point. It works perfectly. Thank you for your help @Pavan.
Another question if you have the time. If you had had to do the same thing. How would you have preceded ? I am curious and I want to progress :)

Answer (score 0):

use the `<%= "#{project.color}" %>` instead of `#{project.color}`